# Интерпретатор brainfuck не строит множество Мандельброта

Tags: c#, интерпретатор, brainfuck

Здравствуйте! Написал интерпретатор brainfuck, простые программы исполняются верно. Но при попытке вывести множество Мандельброта ([код](https://github.com/erikdubbelboer/brainfuck-jit/blob/master/mandelbrot.bf) не мой, но рабочий, проверял [тут](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/) и [тут](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-brainfuck-online)) печатается только несколько строк:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDEGFF
EEEEDDDDDDCCCCCCCCCBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Код:

```
using System;
namespace Bf
{
    public class BfRunner
    {
        private string code;

        private int cpos;
        private int mpos;

        private ushort[] mem;

        public BfRunner(string c)
        {
            code = c;
            cpos = 0;
            mem = new ushort[300000];
            for (int i = 0; i < mem.Length; i++)
                mem[i] = 0;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            cpos = 0;
            mpos = 0;

            while(cpos < code.Length-1)
            {
                char c = code[cpos];
                if (c == '+')
                    mem[mpos]++;

                else if (c == '-')
                    mem[mpos]--;

                else if (c == '<')
                    mpos--;

                else if (c == '>')
                    mpos++;

                else if (c == '.')
                    Console.Write((char)mem[mpos]);

                else if (c == ',')
                    mem[mpos] = (ushort)Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;


                else if (c == '[' && mem[mpos] == 0)
                {
                    int level = 1;
                    while (level != 0)
                    {
                        cpos++;
                        if (code[cpos] == '[')
                            level++;

                        if (code[cpos] == ']')
                            level--;
                    }
                }

                else if (c == ']' && mem[mpos] != 0)
                {
                    int level = 1;

                    while (level != 0)
                    {
                        cpos--;
                        if (code[cpos] == ']')
                            level++;

                        if (code[cpos] == '[')
                            level--;
                    }

                    cpos--;
                }

                cpos++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Посмотрел на ту [реализацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck#.D0.98.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80_Brainfuck), которая лежит на википедии, не нашел отличий.

Не могли бы вы помочь?

---

Проверил, код с вики работает нормально. Становится еще интереснее.